# Deja Dup problem

Tags: 16.04

On my new Ubuntu 16.04, Deja Dup hangs on
/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/revision
and will not go any farther. I even stopped
App Armor and it still hangs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to backup that directory? If so, you should exclude `/dev`, `/sys`, `/proc` and `/tmp` at least. Those folders do hold volatile data.

Comment: But if I exclude the directories you mentioned, then they will be missing on the restore. Is that acceptable?

Comment: I excluded the directories you mentioned above and the Backup finished...but it gave me a huge list of files it did not backup. Again, I wonder if these files will be needed when I do the Restore. I am less than enamored with Deja Dup!

Comment: Those folders hold pseudo filesystems and the content is generated automatically. The folders itself should exist. `/tmp` might be a real filesystem, but there should nothing in there what it is worth for backup.